# Can there be involutions in the unit group of $\mathbb{Z}_n$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Let $x\neq 1$ be an element of the multiplicative group $\mathbb{Z}_n^*$.  Then my question is, is it possible for $x^2$ to equal $1$?

For what $n$ is it possible or impossible?

Comment: Do you mean involutions?

Comment: $(-1)^2 = 1$ always. For a list of all such $x$ you recall the structure of $(\mathbb{Z}/p^r \mathbb{Z})^*$ and then patch them together with the CRT.

Comment: @Mummytheturkey You could post your comment as an answer. Include an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, and most importantly, your title is incorrect.  Idempotents are elements $x\in G$ such that $x^2=x$, and it is an exercise in elementary group theory that the only idempotent in a group is the identity.  As has been mentioned in the comments, it looks like you mean to say *involutions* instead of idempotents, so I answer on this assumption.

In general this is very possible, consider, for example, $4$ modulo $15$ (or indeed $(-1)^2=1$ always as is noted above).  The important thing is that involutions are elements of order $2$.  The general structure of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}^\times$ is well known, (see e.g. the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group_of_integers_modulo_n) page or most good introduction to groups/number theory books).  I give it below:

Firstly, for an odd prime $p$ and positive integer $k$ we have
$$\mathbb{Z}/p^k\mathbb{Z}^\times\cong \mathbb{Z}/(p^k-p^{k-1})\mathbb{Z}.$$

Secondly, at powers of $2$ we have
$$\mathbb{Z}/2^k\mathbb{Z}^\times\cong
\begin{cases}
\{1\}&k=1\\
\mathbb{Z}/2&k=2\\
\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}/2^{k-2}\mathbb{Z} &k\geq 3
\end{cases}$$

The general case then follows from the Chinese remainder theorem, which says that if $n=\prod_{i=1}^rp_i^{k_i}$ is the unique prime decomposition of $n$ then
$$\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}^\times=\prod_{i=1}^r\mathbb{Z}/p_i^{k_i}\mathbb{Z}^\times$$

From the structure of the unit group as a product of cyclic groups in this way, it is easy to see how often (and even how many) involutions appear.